# What's the difference between char* and char when storing a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, syntax

I saw this example:

```
const char* SayHi() { return "Hi"; }
```

And it works fine, but if I try to remove the pointer it doesn't work and I can't figure
 out why.

```
const char SayHi() { return "Hi"; } \\Pointer removed
```

It works if I assign it a single character like this:

```
const char SayHi() { return 'H'; } \\Pointer removed and only 1 character
```

But I don't know what makes it work exactly. Why would a pointer be able to hold more than one character? Isn't a pointer just a variable that points to another one? What does this point to?

Comment: Did you notice this scary warning? __warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast__

Comment: Oh boy, it's really basic stuff... try to find tutorial/books about C++. In this case, think about pointer to char as an array of chars.

Comment: @sharth I don't understand that. return makes integer from pointer without a cast. It's confusing sorry. char is an integer right? return makes it without a cast? Isn't a cast a way to convert a type of variable to another? What is its use here?

Comment: @KenanZahirovic Yes I'm just starting. I'm reading [this](www.learncpp.com/) but I got confused and figured to ask here. I tought that it may be like an array, but is it a rule or is there something I'm missing? Does it work for every variable type? I tought pointers just pointed to the address of another variable, why would it make the char an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because a `char` is by definition a *single* character (like in your 3rd case). If you want a string, you can either use a array of `char`s which decays to `const char*` (like in your first case) or, the C++ way, use `std::string`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c) you can read more about the *"array decaying to pointer"* thing.

Comment: @Metsuryu [An array is not a pointer!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c) Arrays just decay to pointers. (It's a C-answer, applies to C++ too.) Btw you can make code highlight by putting it between '`' .

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a pointer is just a variable that points somewhere -- in this case it points to a string of characters somewhere in memory. By convention, strings (arrays of char) end with a null character (0), so operations like strlen can terminate safely without overflowing a buffer.

As for where that particular pointer (in your first example) points to, it is pointing to the string literal "Hi" (with a null terminator at the end added by the compiler). That location is platform-dependent and is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go).

It is also better practice to use std::string in C++ than plain C arrays of characters.

Comment: This makes it clearer, thanks. So char* creates an array when pointing to more than one value automatically? I guess this was not really clear to me.

Comment: See the last part of my answer.